# Allow user to select the data to plot in plotly r

Tags: r, r-plotly

I am trying to plot a chart where the user can select which column data they want to view in the plot. So if you see in the data below I want to plot a chart where the user can see the numbers by date for differnt fruits . So x axis should be the date, y axis should me either market1 , market2 or market3 which ever the user select and a area chart where the areas as split by fruit type.

```
test_data <-data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
       market1 = c(0L,0L,1L,0L,0L,1L,1L,0L,
                       2L,2L,0L,0L,1L,0L,8L,8L,0L,4L,3L,0L,4L,2L,
                       0L,1L,2L,0L,3L,2L,0L,5L,0L,7L,1L,8L,4L,0L,
                       16L,22L,0L,35L,17L,57L,19L,0L,125L,15L,0L,49L,
                       18L,0L),
            market2 = c(34L,5L,71L,3L,3L,30L,54L,
                       0L,15L,28L,0L,24L,53L,0L,169L,46L,0L,134L,40L,
                       0L,123L,18L,2L,54L,72L,0L,131L,44L,0L,111L,
                       35L,194L,19L,182L,65L,0L,462L,313L,0L,524L,300L,
                       1366L,216L,0L,2165L,297L,0L,1188L,196L,0L),
       market3 = c(1762L,1139L,2562L,294L,235L,
                       890L,1619L,1L,453L,1434L,6L,872L,1933L,12L,
                       3951L,1563L,20L,2934L,2358L,126L,5182L,2264L,208L,
                       3897L,2735L,3L,3156L,2727L,8L,3667L,1273L,4819L,
                       679L,5470L,1829L,7L,9847L,7309L,30L,9235L,7933L,
                       30486L,4551L,2L,35029L,7018L,3L,25591L,3516L,1L),
          fruit = c("Apple",
                       "Apple","Apple",
                       "Apple","Apple","Apple",
                       "Apple","Apple",
                       "Apple","Apple","Apple",
                       "Apple","Banana",
                       "Banana","Banana","Banana",
                       "Banana","Banana",
                       "Banana","Banana","Banana",
                       "Banana","Banana",
                       "Banana","Banana","Banana",
                       "Orange","Orange",
                       "Orange","Orange","Orange",
                       "Orange","Orange",
                       "Orange","Orange","Orange",
                       "Orange","Orange",
                       "Orange","Berries","Berries",
                       "Berries","Berries",
                       "Berries","Berries","Berries",
                       "Berries","Berries",
                       "Berries","Berries"),
              date = as.factor(c("1/10/20",
                                 "1/10/20","1/10/20","1/10/20","1/10/20",
                                 "1/10/20","1/11/20","1/11/20","1/11/20",
                                 "1/11/20","1/11/20","1/11/20","1/12/20","1/12/20",
                                 "1/12/20","1/12/20","1/12/20","1/12/20",
                                 "1/13/20","1/13/20","1/13/20","1/13/20",
                                 "1/13/20","1/13/20","1/14/20","1/14/20",
                                 "1/14/20","1/14/20","1/14/20","1/14/20","1/15/20",
                                 "1/15/20","1/15/20","1/15/20","1/16/20",
                                 "1/16/20","1/16/20","1/16/20","1/16/20",
                                 "1/16/20","1/17/20","1/17/20","1/17/20",
                                 "1/17/20","1/17/20","1/18/20","1/18/20","1/18/20",
                                 "1/18/20","1/18/20"))
)
```

I tried doing it for just one market but I am unable to split it by fruit. How can I go about it.Below is the code for the plot.

```
plot_ly(test_data, x = test_data$date, y = test_data$market1, name = 'Tastemade', type = 'scatter', mode = 'none', stackgroup = 'one', fillcolor = '#F5FF8D')
  layout(title = 'Conversions By Day',
         #  xaxis = list(title = 'Date',rangeslider = list(type = "date")),
         xaxis = list(title = 'Date'),
         yaxis = list(title = 'Conversions'))
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can create a plot where the user will be allowed to change the y-axis variable, unless you create a shiny app.

Here is an example of a scatter plot for market1, where the markers are coloured by fruit:

```
plot_ly(data = test_data, x = ~date, y = ~market1, color = ~fruit, colors = "RdYlGn", 
        type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers') %>% 
layout(title = 'Conversions By Day',
       #  xaxis = list(title = 'Date',rangeslider = list(type = "date")),
       xaxis = list(title = 'Date'),
       yaxis = list(title = 'Conversions'))
```